# How do I monitor a Google doc's live update with Wireshark?

Tags: networking, google-docs, wireshark, web-traffic, network-monitoring

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how Google docs makes and handles requests for changes in documents on the fly, and am wondering if there is something specific I could be monitoring with Wireshark.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs uses HTTPS to encrypt its communication. You cannot monitor any specific content-related changes, only witness that a user is contacting `docs.google.com`.

That said, if you're willing to delve into the realm of [timing](http://www.ieee-security.org/TC/SP2011/PAPERS/2011/paper001.pdf) [analysis](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~dawnsong/papers/ssh-timing.pdf), you may be able to reconstruct details from encrypted sessions. But this requires a significant amount of manual work.